# How to use a specific version of Node/NPM in BASH without using nvm?

Tags: node.js, windows-10, command-line-interface, git-bash, nvm

Context: I'm using my work laptop, so I don't have admin privileges. I'm on Windows 10 using Git BASH

I had the latest version of Node and was trying to use a certain package from npm ([@servicenow/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@servicenow/cli?activeTab=code)), but it's only compatible with Node version 12.16.1, so I downloaded [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to install and use said version.

(I was originally using regular nvm with BASH but it wasn't connecting with whatever source it connects with to download different Node versions but nvm-windows does work).

I was able to use nvm-windows to install the version of Node I need (12.16.1). It's in `C:\Users\Username\nvm\v12.16.1` and it shows up in BASH if I use the command `nvm list`.

However, I can't use the command `nvm use 12.16.1` to switch to Node 12.16.1 because it requires elevated admin privileges. From nvm-windows docs:

> NVM for Windows "switches" versions of node.js by updating a symlink, using the mklink command. The symlink is recreated to point to whichever version of node.js should run. This process requires elevated administrative permissions.

So, my question is, does anyone know how I can use the version of Node I have without using nvm-windows? There's a node.exe in `C:\Users\Username\nvm\v12.16.1` but when I execute it, it's just a Node repl (I thought I would be able to use npm there, ha)

Despite having this version of Node installed, the Node and npm commands don't work. My intuition tells me that I can use Environment Variables to point to this version of Node so the commands work in the terminal , but I'm not sure how I would do that, exactly.

Due to not having admin privileges, I can't edit the System environment variables, but I can edit the **User** environment variables for my Windows User and *I think* it works similarly. (I had to add two User variables during the manual installation of nvm-windows. I'm not sure what they do/what they're for exactly, but I think it's so the nvm commands work in the terminal?)

Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I just needed to edit the Path User variable and concatenate the path to the directory that contains the version of Node to the end. The Node and npm commands work now.

1. Open file explorer and navigate to the directory that contains the
   version of Node you want to use
2. Double click on the path bar and copy the path
3. Windows key, Edit environment variables for your account
4. Double click on Path variable
5. Click on "Edit text" on the right side
6. Navigate to the end and paste the path you copied and hit Ok, hit Ok again
7. Open terminal and do node -v and npm -v to verify it works